# how to sortarray with minimum complexcity?

Tags: java

can you please tell me how to sort given array ?
**[0,1,1,0,0,.....n times ]**with minimum compexity;
I try like that

```
for (int i=0;i<n/2;i++){
if(a[i]>a[n-i])
swap code

}
```

is it the best way ?

Second question : we do sometime like this

```
Button btn =new button;
Btn.setchangelistner(new OnclickListner);
```

OnclickListner is interface why it is use with new

same as `**new runnable**`

Comment: Don't take any shortcuts when posting questions.

Comment: Separate out your questions. Don;t post two in one, it jut makes it harder to answer

Comment: Please define minimum complexity. `Arrays.sort(a);` is really simple. Also, your way doesn't work. Your second question is incomplete, but I think you're asking what are [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Comment: Do you want to *create* a method to do this for you? Or do you want to do it like everyone else is suggesting with one line of code: `Arrays.sort(a);`?

Comment: want creat a simple method

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way

```
Arrays.sort(a);
```

Comment: I need some algo with minimum complexity ? no use inbuid funtion

Comment: I don't want Array.sort :(

Comment: @user2648752 **Then say that in your question.**

Comment: @user2648752 Array.sort() is the best algorithm for real world problem sizes.

Comment: Question is to sort an array without using inbuild java function.you can use bubble sort

Answer (score 1):

You should always use Arrays.sort() to sort an array because it is extremely efficient. It uses a version of the quicksort algorithm:

> Sorts the specified array of bytes into ascending numerical order. The sorting algorithm is a tuned quicksort, adapted from Jon L. Bentley and M. Douglas McIlroy's "Engineering a Sort Function", Software-Practice and Experience, Vol. 23(11) P. 1249-1265 (November 1993). This algorithm offers n*log(n) performance on many data sets that cause other quicksorts to degrade to quadratic performance.

Don't try to sort an array by yourself unless there is a specific way you want it sorted. Arrays.sort() will be able to do it a lot faster and use a lot less memory.

N*logN (quicksort) is the most efficient algorithm at large problem sizes. If you have a very small problem size then there are more efficient algorithms but for any real world problem sizes, this is the best algorithm.

to sum up:

```
int array[] = new int[1000];

// fill array

Arrays.sort(array);

// you are passing your array as a pointer
// so there is no need for assignment here.
```

---

Edit:

I came up with a simple sorting algorithm that comes out to be linear time if the array has only 1s and 0s. There are better solutions out there but this should get you started:

```
/**
 * This will sort an array of just 1s and 0s
 * 
 * @param array the array to sort
 */
public int[] simpleSort(int[] array)
{
    int[] sorted = new int[array.length];
    int start1 = 0; // where to start putting 1s
    int end0 = sorted.length - 1; // where to start putting 0s

    for(int x = 0;x < sorted.length;x++)
    {
        if(array[x] == 1)
        {
            sorted[start1] = 1;
            start1++;
        }else{
            sorted[end0] = 0;
            end0--;
        }
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: I don't use inbuid function of java .I want to make own sorting program

Comment: @user2648752 Do you want code for writing an actual sorting function?

Comment: yes ..without using array.sort

Comment: @user2648752 see my algorithm

Comment: bUT IT COMPLEXITY IS N.i already reduce to n/2 in my question

Comment: N/2 is impossible for this problem. There is no way to sort an array without iterating over all of the elements. All sorting algorithms have at least O(N) complexity. NLogN is considered to be extremely efficient in sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Question one:

```
Array a = ["1", "2", "Hello", "World"];

Arrays.sort(a);
```

That should do it.

I'm not sure exactly what you are asking in question two. You should re-submit it as a separate question and make it clearer.

Comment: `Arrays.sort(a)` will not return a value. It's a procedure; it will modify the array to be sorted. I didn't downvote, but that's why someone did. I'll upvote if you change your answer.

Comment: Array having only zero and one elements ..

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the obvious [<kbd>Arrays.sort()</kbd>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) method like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

Arrays.sort(array);
```

I have created an insertion sorting algorithm method to sort an `int[]` (the comments are from when I was a noob programmer). Insertion seems to work the fastest for me and all my attempts.

```
public int[] sort(int[] array) // public static int[] sort(int[] array)
{
    int pass = 0, comp = 0; // represents pass as the position, in the array, of the value being inserted; and comp, as the comparison variable, that is the value being inserted.
    int temp; // represents a temporary int to assist in switching array values.

    for (pass = 1; pass < array.length; pass++) // for every position in the array (except the first element)...
    {
        comp = pass; // have the comparison/insertion variable be equal to which pass the method is on.

        while (comp > 0) // only do this while the comparison/insertion variable position is greater than 0 (because otherwise it wouldn't have any adjacent positions (to the left) left).

            if (array[comp] < array[comp - 1]) // if the comparison/insertion value is less than its adjacent position (to the left), swap the values:
            {   
                temp = array[comp]; // set the temporary variable to hold the value of the comparison/insertion variable's value.
                array[comp] = array[comp - 1]; // change the comparison/insertion variable's value to be its adjacent positions value.
                array[comp - 1] = temp; // set the adjacent positions value to be the temporary variable's value.
                comp --; // set the comparison to be backwards 1 to keep checking where it needs to finally be inserted.
            }
            else // otherwise (if the comparison variable value is greater than or equal to its adjacent position to the left)...
            { 
                break; // exit the do loop to avoid an endless cycle.
            }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Sample input/use:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] array = {54, 7, 2, 7, 15, 16};
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(sort(array)));
}
```

> [2, 7, 7, 15, 16, 54]

Comment: Array having only o and 1 element

Comment: @user2648752 It will work for that as well.

Comment: But want is the complexity ?

Comment: @user2648752 I have no idea what you're trying to say. Sorry.

Comment: The complexity of this algorithm looks to be N*N or maybe NLogN, not sure. Either way you simply cannot get an algorithm down to N / 2 for sorting.